# Filter data from a created list

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am working on my Covid data set  from github and I would like to  filter my data set with the countries that appear in the this [EU_member list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv) in csv format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv')
df = df[df.continent == 'Europe']

# From here I want to  just pick those countries that appear in the following list:
EU_members= ['Austria','Italy','Belgium''Latvia','Bulgaria','Lithuania','Croatia','Luxembourg','Cyprus','Malta','Czechia','Netherlands','Denmark','Poland','Estonia',
'Portugal','Finland','Romania','France','Slovakia','Germany','Slovenia','Greece','Spain','Hungary','Sweden','Ireland']

# I have tried something like this but it is not what I expected:
df.location.str.find('EU_members')
```

Comment: What is your question about this?

Comment: How to filter  the dataset that only contains the  countries that I have created in the **EU_member** list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.isin()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/owid-covid-data.csv')

EU_members= ['Austria','Italy','Belgium''Latvia','Bulgaria','Lithuania','Croatia','Luxembourg','Cyprus','Malta','Czechia','Netherlands','Denmark','Poland','Estonia',
'Portugal','Finland','Romania','France','Slovakia','Germany','Slovenia','Greece','Spain','Hungary','Sweden','Ireland']


df_out = df[df['location'].isin(EU_members)]
df_out.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Creates `data.csv`:

[image]